# Asymptotics for prime factors

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics

Am I correct in assuming that the same result:
$$
N_k(x):=\ \mid\{n\leq x : \Omega(n)=k\}\mid \ \sim \frac{x}{\log x}\frac{(\log_2 x)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\ (x \rightarrow \infty)
$$
also holds for:
$$
\pi_k(x):=\ \mid\{n\leq x : \omega(n)=k\}\mid \
$$
even though they are wildly different for high $k$? See [here.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35927/asymptotic-density-of-k-almost-primes)

Comment: There may be something useful in the references and links at http://oeis.org/A001221 and at http://oeis.org/A013939